# What happens to the signal and antenna pattern when the coaxial shield of the feedline is severed?

Tags: rf, antenna, transmission-line, coax, coaxial

Assuming a single-shielded coaxial cable connected between a transceiver and antenna, what would happen to transmitted signal and the antenna's radiation pattern if at some point along the feedline the outer shielding is severed completely?

Comment: Coax relies on the shield being grounded and, if a section of the shield becomes ungrounded then it isn't behaving like coax any more.

Comment: What kind of antenna are you talking about?  A simple dipole?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes I'm aware. I was looking for a more specific answer. Pertaining to both the signal being sent and the antenna's pattern.

Comment: @SteveSh Let's say some PCB antenna like a Yagi, log periodic, or even a quad patch array.

Comment: @SteveSh a simple dipole is unsuited to coax without a balun.

Comment: As far as the radiation pattern goes, that depends on the type of antenna element you're dealing with.  For example, a patch radiator needs a ground plane under it to operate properly.  So long as the ground plane still exists and is connected to ground, that I don't think the element pattern itself would change.

Comment: If the outer shielding of the coax is severed then the ground plane is no longer part of the circuit. So the pattern would change.

Answer (score 2):

> what would happen to transmitted signal and the antenna's radiation
> pattern if at some point along the feedline the outer shielding is
> severed completely?

The unconnected (end) piece of coax becomes a radiating element. Transmitted power divides three ways:

- some RF power reaches the antenna.
- some RF power is radiated by the ungrounded feedline.
- some RF power is dissipated by the section of feedline between transmitter and break as heat.

In addition, the transmitter *likely* generate less power than it otherwise would into a proper load - the severed coax shield disturbs this load impedance. Some transmitters refuse to deliver power to loads having outlier impedance, or they cut-back power by design.

As for the radiation pattern - who knows? With multiple radiating elements in some strange spatial configuration, we cannot tell.

Comment: To be clear, I believe when you say "the unconnected (end) piece of coax becomes a radiating element" you are referring to the piece on the transmitter's side. The disconnected shielding of the connected to the antenna's ground doesn't do anything, right?

Comment: The disconnected end becomes a radiator, perhaps an inefficient one. The section between transmitter and broken coax shield can radiate too, since currents can now flow on the **outside** of the coax.